# changing the font in a JTextArea for different lines

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I would like to append differnt lines of font to the JTextArea, however the last font seems to override the other.

Please help...

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class test extends JFrame {

private static JTextArea referenceTextArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public test() {
    this.add(panel);
    panel.add(referenceTextArea);
}

public static void textTest() {
    referenceTextArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 15));
    referenceTextArea.append("line1");
    referenceTextArea.append("\n");

    referenceTextArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 30));
    referenceTextArea.append("line2");
    referenceTextArea.append("\n");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test frame = new test();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textTest();
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using JEditorPane / JTextPane

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

These support HTML formatting. A normal JTextArea's setFont method will just set the font for the entire textarea.